# My docker starts zookeeper, but it then automatically exists

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i write dockfile start zookeeper

```
FROM buildpack-deps:sid-scm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bzip2 \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
        gettext-base \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY zookeeper-3.4.12.tar.gz /opt
COPY config.template.properties /opt
RUN tar xfz /opt/zookeeper-3.4.12.tar.gz -C /opt
ENV ZK_HOME /opt/zookeeper-3.4.12
COPY startzookeeper.sh /opt
RUN  chmod a+x /opt/startzookeeper.sh $ZK_HOME
CMD   ["/opt/startzookeeper.sh"]
```

the startzookeeper.sh file is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

eval "cat <<EOF
$(</opt/config.template.properties)
EOF
" | tee /opt/zoo.cfg 2> /dev/null


#echo "$ZK_HOME" > 2.txt
cp /opt/zoo.cfg "$ZK_HOME"/conf
#
exec "$ZK_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh" start
```

but when i run docker ps,it is empty.
i try add tail -f /dev/null,but it does not work.
i don't know why,the zookeeper should run always,why it exist?
thanks any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt your script to imitate the one from the official [zookeeper-docker](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/0e558d7a6df4031a6be7c1df4ba1e2367666d004/3.4.12/Dockerfile)
 (from [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper/))

Its [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/0e558d7a6df4031a6be7c1df4ba1e2367666d004/3.4.12/docker-entrypoint.sh) ends with `exec "$@"`, which executes [`"zkServer.sh", "start-foreground"`.](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/bin/zkServer.sh)

The important part is the [`start-foreground` option](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/28de451aa8b45e94d1261d5e0e369f86bf3815da/bin/zkServer.sh#L191-L200), which ensures the process does not exit immediately, as that would exit your container as well.